# Check if an stl file may contain two models

Tags: c#, 3d, computational-geometry

An stl file may contain 2 3D models. Is there any way I can detect if there are 2 or more models stored in one stl file?

In my current code, it can detect that there are 2 models in the example, but there are instances that it detects a lot of model even though it only has one.

> The Triangle class structure has Vertices that contains 3 points (x, y, z)..

Sample STL File:

[image]

> EDIT: Using @Gebb's answer this is how I implemented it:

```
private int GetNumberOfModels(List<TopoVertex> vertices)
    {
        Vertex[][] triangles = new Vertex[vertices.Count() / 3][];

        int vertIdx = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Count() / 3; i++)
        {
            Vertex v1 = new Vertex(vertices[vertIdx].pos.x, vertices[vertIdx].pos.y, vertices[vertIdx].pos.z);
            Vertex v2 = new Vertex(vertices[vertIdx + 1].pos.x, vertices[vertIdx + 1].pos.y, vertices[vertIdx + 1].pos.z);
            Vertex v3 = new Vertex(vertices[vertIdx + 2].pos.x, vertices[vertIdx + 2].pos.y, vertices[vertIdx + 2].pos.z);

            triangles[i] = new Vertex[] { v1, v2, v3 };
            vertIdx += 3;
        }
        var uniqueVertices = new HashSet<Vertex>(triangles.SelectMany(t => t));
        int vertexCount = uniqueVertices.Count;
        // The DisjointUnionSets class works with integers, so we need a map from vertex
        // to integer (its id).

        Dictionary<Vertex, int> indexedVertices = uniqueVertices
            .Zip(
                Enumerable.Range(0, vertexCount),
                (v, i) => new { v, i })
            .ToDictionary(vi => vi.v, vi => vi.i);

        int[][] indexedTriangles =
            triangles
            .Select(t => t.Select(v => indexedVertices[v]).ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        var du = new XYZ.view.wpf.DisjointUnionSets(vertexCount);

        // Iterate over the "triangles" consisting of vertex ids.
        foreach (int[] triangle in indexedTriangles)
        {
            int vertex0 = triangle[0];
            // Mark 0-th vertexes connected component as connected to those of all other vertices.
            foreach (int v in triangle.Skip(1))
            {
                du.Union(vertex0, v);
            }
        }

        var connectedComponents =
            new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, vertexCount).Select(x => du.Find(x)));
        return connectedComponents.Count;
    }
```

> In some cases, it produces the correct output, but for the example image above, it outputs **3** instead of **2**. I am now trying to optimize the snippet @Gebb gave to use float values since I believe that the floating points are necessary to the comparisons. Does anyone have a way to do that as well? Maybe I need another perspective.

Comment: The type `new HashSet<float>` to represent vertices doesn't seem right, a vertex cannot be represented by just one number, it has three coordinates.

Comment: I agree, the code `triangles.SelectMany(t => t)` decomposes x,y and z and throws all floats on a pile. In other words `vertexCount = uniqueVertices.Count` is off by a factor of 3.

Comment: @Gebb , How do I optimize it to fit for the floating points of vertices?

Comment: @Funk What to do though? I am still trying to use the snippet Gebb gave to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by representing vertices and connections between them as a graph and finding the number of connected components of the graph with the help of the [Disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Vertex = System.ValueTuple<double,double,double>;

namespace UnionFindSample
{
    internal class DisjointUnionSets
    {
        private readonly int _n;
        private readonly int[] _rank;
        private readonly int[] _parent;

        public DisjointUnionSets(int n)
        {
            _rank = new int[n];
            _parent = new int[n];
            _n = n;
            MakeSet();
        }

        // Creates n sets with single item in each
        public void MakeSet()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _n; i++)
                // Initially, all elements are in
                // their own set.
                _parent[i] = i;
        }

        // Finds the representative of the set
        // that x is an element of.
        public int Find(int x)
        {
            if (_parent[x] != x)
            {
                // if x is not the parent of itself, then x is not the representative of
                // his set.
                // We do the path compression by moving x’s node directly under the representative
                // of this set.
                _parent[x] = Find(_parent[x]);
            }

            return _parent[x];
        }

        // Unites the set that includes x and
        // the set that includes x
        public void Union(int x, int y)
        {
            // Find representatives of two sets.
            int xRoot = Find(x), yRoot = Find(y);

            // Elements are in the same set, no need to unite anything.
            if (xRoot == yRoot)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_rank[xRoot] < _rank[yRoot])
            {
                // Then move x under y so that depth of tree remains equal to _rank[yRoot].
                _parent[xRoot] = yRoot;
            }
            else if (_rank[yRoot] < _rank[xRoot])
            {
                // Then move y under x so that depth of tree remains equal to _rank[xRoot].
                _parent[yRoot] = xRoot;
            }
            else
            {
                // if ranks are the same
                // then move y under x (doesn't matter which one goes where).
                _parent[yRoot] = xRoot;

                // And increment the result tree's
                // rank by 1
                _rank[xRoot] = _rank[xRoot] + 1;
            }
        }
    }


    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = args[0];
            Vertex[][] triangles = ParseStl(file);
            var uniqueVertices = new HashSet<Vertex>(triangles.SelectMany(t => t));
            int vertexCount = uniqueVertices.Count;
            // The DisjointUnionSets class works with integers, so we need a map from vertex
            // to integer (its id).
            Dictionary<Vertex, int> indexedVertices = uniqueVertices
                .Zip(
                    Enumerable.Range(0, vertexCount),
                    (v, i) => new {v, i})
                .ToDictionary(vi => vi.v, vi => vi.i);
            int[][] indexedTriangles =
                triangles
                .Select(t => t.Select(v => indexedVertices[v]).ToArray())
                .ToArray();

            var du = new DisjointUnionSets(vertexCount);

            // Iterate over the "triangles" consisting of vertex ids.
            foreach (int[] triangle in indexedTriangles)
            {
                int vertex0 = triangle[0];
                // Mark 0-th vertexes connected component as connected to those of all other vertices.
                foreach (int v in triangle.Skip(1))
                {
                    du.Union(vertex0, v);
                }
            }

            var connectedComponents =
                new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, vertexCount).Select(x => du.Find(x)));
            int count = connectedComponents.Count;
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of connected components: {count}.");
            var groups = triangles.GroupBy(t => du.Find(indexedVertices[t[0]]));
            foreach (IGrouping<int, Vertex[]> g in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Group id={g.Key}:");
                foreach (Vertex[] triangle in g)
                {
                    string tr = string.Join(' ', triangle);
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{tr}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static Regex _triangleStart = new Regex(@"^\s+outer loop");
        private static Regex _triangleEnd = new Regex(@"^\s+endloop");
        private static Regex _vertex = new Regex(@"^\s+vertex\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)");


        private static Vertex[][] ParseStl(string file)
        {
            double ParseCoordinate(GroupCollection gs, int i) =>
                double.Parse(gs[i].Captures[0].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var triangles = new List<Vertex[]>();
            bool isInsideTriangle = false;
            List<Vertex> triangle = new List<Vertex>();
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                if (isInsideTriangle)
                {
                    if (_triangleEnd.IsMatch(line))
                    {
                        isInsideTriangle = false;
                        triangles.Add(triangle.ToArray());
                        triangle = new List<Vertex>();
                        continue;
                    }

                    Match vMatch = _vertex.Match(line);
                    if (vMatch.Success)
                    {
                        double x1 = ParseCoordinate(vMatch.Groups, 1);
                        double x2 = ParseCoordinate(vMatch.Groups, 2);
                        double x3 = ParseCoordinate(vMatch.Groups, 3);
                        triangle.Add((x1, x2, x3));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_triangleStart.IsMatch(line))
                    {
                        isInsideTriangle = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return triangles.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using the fact that `System.ValueTuple` implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in an appropriate way, so we can easily compare vertices (this is used implicitly by `HashSet`) and use them as keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I am getting an error in the declaration of the triangles. https://imgur.com/a/ULyGJcl

Comment: It's .net Core and c#7. I believe I did not use anything from c#8.

Comment: I used your code and implemented in mine.I am using the vertices with float values and sometime, even in one model, it produces the output of 3.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1irXiyEsNJaaHVmGSFBe5KCcEHq3Hrfoo this is my test file. You can see the vertices in Notepad++ since it's in ascii. this gives me **3** as the count using your answer but it only has two.

Comment: I believe the floating points are vital to the checking. I implemented your code and sometimes and can count really well.

Comment: Ah, yes, it might be that checking floating point numbers for precise equality is the problem. Maybe you should have a structure representing a vertex that checks for equality with some tolerance.

Comment: @TerribleDog or you made a mistake in the code somewhere. I copied vertex coordinates from the file you provided to my program, changed the type of coordinate from `int` to `double`, and got two components. See https://ideone.com/6lFfD2

Comment: I added a simple regexp-based STL parser to my answer, so if you run the program with the path to your sample file as an argument, you get *2* in the output.

Comment: It's okay now. I integrated the snippet into my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you think there is any way to use this approach to separate the vertices of the two models inside the file?

Comment: Well, you can identify which "group" each vertex belongs to, but what do you men by "separate"? Create a separate .stl file for each group?

Comment: I updated my answer to output the groups of triangles to the console.